# Why are my breakpoints in Visual Studio Code are not bound in Angular application?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, debugging, vscode-debugger

I followed this Angular debugging tutorial (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/angular-tutorial) but when I launch the debugger, my breakpoints are not bound. I confirmed "sourceMap" is set to true in my tsconfig.json file and angular.json file. Below is a snippet of my app.component.ts file, and the Debug Diagnostics. Any ideas why my breakpoints aren't being bound?

I have Angular CLI version 16.1.8 and Node version 18.16.1

[image]

[image]